# Get many parameters from a single flag C++

Tags: c++, parsing, parameters, arguments

I'm looking for a library or an "elegant" way of parsing arguments to my program that doesn't follow the usual argument patterns.

Usually, arguments would be flags (like `-a`), parameters (`-a value`) or positional parameters as seen [here](https://github.com/adishavit/argh).

What if my program takes parameters such as `-a v1 v2 v3` where v1 v2 and v3 are directly related to `-a` and are not positional parameters per se.

Further, in my program (which takes in these parameters manually) I can even get `-a v1 v2 v3 -b x1 x2 x3` where `-b` is also related to `-a` and wouldn't make sense outside of it.

As in `-cat fluffy brown friendly -name snuffles`

Where snuffles only makes sense for the given cat (that's just a silly example).

Comment: So, you have to define a formal language for your arguments. The tokenizer is provided e.g. by a `for` loop which reads the arguments. (Are you sure you don't want a config file which provides the parameters?) However, concerning the parsing, I don't see much difference whether the tokens are provided by commandline arguments or a lexer which reads a file. (You even might consider to provide both. I believe I once saw a certain program which did so when I worked on Irix/Linux in the past but I cannot remember clearly anymore.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this vexing problem is to stop doing that.  A good baseline guide is the [GNU Coding Standards for Command Line Interfaces](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html).

Note that Bash or other shells can help you achieve compact syntax without doing strange things in your program code.  For example, instead of `myprog -a v1 v2 v3`, do this in Bash, and your program will see a full and proper `-av1 -av2 -av3` after shell expansion:

```
myprog -a{v1,v2,v3}
myprog -av{1..3}
```

By doing it this way, any decent library for CLI argument parsing will work, and you won't need to work around endless corner cases.

Regarding the `-a -b` case where `-b` is supposed to be an argument to `-a`, the problem goes away once you put `-a` in front of it:

```
myprog -a{v1,v2,v3,-b,x1,x2,x3}
```

Comment: Yes, that would indeed solve it, but it would break every script running the code :(

Comment: @mjgalindo: Are you saying you already have an implementation of the required syntax?  If so, what is the question exactly?  Just keep the existing code.

Comment: There is an implementation, but it needs to be extended and maintained so I intended to use a library to simplify the code before it gets bigger and more unmanageable

Comment: Oh I see.  Well, you cannot expect any "command line parsing" library to support all the weird things you are doing.

Comment: I see, it was worth a try :)

Comment: How about adding one flag to the existing program which says "use the new parser", then you can gradually migrate your scripts to pass that flag, keeping both parsing implementations until all scripts are migrated, then finally you can remove the "use the new parser" flag and the old code.

Comment: If this was a serious, deployed system that'd be what I'd do, but it's more of a research oriented project so if the change won't make things immediately simpler it's better not to do it. That would make the code worse for now. Still, thanks for your interest :)